# Row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns is given. Determine the number of possible echelon matrices that satisfy the following condition: each row has a leading entry and the elements of the matrix are either 1 or 0.

I am stuck finding the solution. Can anyone help

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of Row-echelon form?

Comment: I have tried but it not give me the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The above is a matrix in row echelon form. However, you have the added restriction of all entries being 1 or 0. Also, you have 4 columns, 3 rows, and each row has a leading entry.

The fact that there's a leading entry in each row means that, the matrix must contain the following columns, ordered this way, from left to right:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \ast & \ast  \\ 0 & 1 & \ast  \\ 0& 0& 1 \\  \end{bmatrix}$$

However, you're not done yet. You are missing a column, whose form depends on where it is inserted. There are three cases.

Can you continue?

Comment: OK, thank you. I figured it out by myself. The answer is 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3